# Prevent Webpack ProvidePlugin to replace identifiers on node_modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Right now I've a ProvidePlugin replacement defined as:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({  Image: [ 'components/Image', 'default' ] })
```

But this is also replacing the `Image`definition of libraries located on `node_modules`

Is there a way to specify the folder where the identifiers are located to avoid unwanted replacements on the `node_modules` folder?

e.g.:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({  "Image in /src/components": [ 'components/Image', 'default' ] })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, by default `ProvidePlugin` api have resolution path is current `(./**)`folder and `node_modules` by their definition.

To restrict it to a certain folder to look to, You can do:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  Image: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'src/components'))
});
```

Comment: I think what that rule does is find where the module that's going to be provided is located in a specific folder and what I'm trying to achieve is to solve Identifiers that are in a specific folder.

Something like *import `Image component` just on the following folders ... /src/views*

Comment: I get it now, what you wanted